# Changing Hitbox from a single spritesheet

Tags: c#, 2d, monogame

I have different animation in a single spritesheet. I wonder how do you guys assigning these hitboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend to put sprites of different sizes in one file.

As example, my movement animation is e.g. 64x64px and my attack animation is 96x96px. Therefore I have one file for the movement animation and one for the attack animation.

May sound to produce some clutter but in fact it is better to seperate those animation. Imagin if you want to have different animations for different actions (e.g. wielding a huge axe compared to fire a gun)
If you put everything into one file with different frame sizes it will probably end up beeing a mess.